# Chrome Extension Tab Favicon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension I'm building  and have included the tabs permission in my manifest file:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
 ],
```

In my javascript file I am using

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
```

to get a list of my tabs and this is all working fine, however I don't get the faviconUrl field in my return objects.

I have tried looping through them used

```
chrome.tabs.get(item.id, function(data) {
```

But I just get the same object data through.

Does anyone have any idea why faviconUrl is not appearing in my results?

Comment: perhaps because the [tab hasn't finished loading yet](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab)? Not sure when you try to get the `favIconUrl` but it is a possibility.

Comment: @IvyLynx is referring to this quote in the docs: "It may also be an empty string if the tab is loading."

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I did see that in the docs, but I've been testing it on a window that's been open for a few hours with no changes to the tabs.

Comment: what do you get when you console.log(tabs) from tabs.query callback?... and it's favIconUrl (capital I), maybe you are using it something like tab.faviconUrl (which is wrong)

Comment: I was being a big dumbo all along! It is working, but by coincidence I was only inspecting the objects of the tabs that have no favicon every time. I assumed it would bring back an empty string for no favicon as well as a loading tab. Guess that shows you what happens when you assume things!

Comment: mark as resolved, or answer your own question.

Answer (score 2):

The faviconUrl field is not returned at all if the tab does not have a favicon!